# If $\underline{u}$ is a vector, does $u$ indicate its magnitude?

Tags: vectors, conventions, notation

If $\underline{u}$ is a vector, does $u$ indicate its magnitude? $|\underline{u}|$ also indicates the magnitude, doesn't it?

Comment: $u$ is a magnitude, but what if $u$ is negative? Are there any implications or scenarios where this might matter at all, and the absolute value provides insight?

Comment: Sometimes $u$ can also indicate a vector, especially in more mathematical texts.

Comment: It very often indicates the magnitude, but not always. If an author is using it in some other way then they ought to say so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|\underline{u}|$ also indicates the magnitude, doesn't it? - Yes.

The problem is that there are a number of conventions which people use and misuse.

The notation for a vector can be written as $\underline u, \,\vec u$ and $\mathbf u$.

Without any further information perhaps the "safest" way forward is to assume that $u$ represents the component of a vector in a given direction.

So $\underline u = u\,\hat u$ where $\hat u$ is unit vector in some given direction and $u$ is the component of vector $\underline u$ in the $\hat u$ direction.

As an example, you might write $\underline x = -3 \hat i$ but it could also be written as $\underline x = -3 \hat x$ where $\hat i = \hat x$ as alternative labels for the unit vector pointing in the positive x-direction.

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, $|.|$ (i.e. the double bars) in $|\underline{u}|$ don't have anything to do with absolute values, do they?

Comment: [What does double vertical-line means in linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586245/what-does-double-vertical-line-means-in-linear-algebra)

Comment: Oh, I see. So, in this case, $|.|$ is just indicating the norm.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out, there are various conventions. To answer your first question, while not always the case, it is very common for $u$ to denote the magnitude of $\underline{u}$, so that $\underline{u}=u\hat u$, where $\hat u$ is the unit normal vector in the direction of $\underline{u}$. To use Farcher's example, if $\underline{u} = -3\hat i$, following this convention,
$u = 3$ and $\hat u = -\hat i$.